# AJAX error when passing a variable to a PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

How my page works:

1. The quiz php page loads and the user generates a score with a function inside `quiz.js`. The score is then saved in a variable `score` inside `quiz.js`
2. After generating the score, the user has to press a button to go to the next question in the quiz inside the same page. Pressing the button would send the score to my database with a sql query I have in `sendData.php`, without reloading the page.

My button looks like this:

```
<form id="sendData" action="sendData.php" method="post">
  <button type="submit" name="send" onclick="sendAjax()">Send</button>
</form>
```

`sendData.php` is already finished and working, but for some reason, sendAjax() doesn't work at all:

```
function sendAjax() {
  $.ajax({
    url:  "sendData.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      score: score,
      numQuiz: numQuiz
    },
    success: function() {
      alert("Data succesfully sent");
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("There has been an error");
    }
  })
}
```

And my PHP file being like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['score']) and isset($_POST['numQuiz'])) {
    $score = $_POST['score'];
    $numQuiz = $_POST['numQuiz'];
    // SQL query and stuff goes here
}
```

But it seems that `$_POST['score']` and `$_POST['numQuiz']` aren't set. Also, I can see the error pop up inside `sendAjax` before it loads the PHP file. I've tried adding to the form the attribute `action=""` but it doesn't work either.

Comment: remove submit from button

Comment: still not working :/

Comment: You have to do `.preventDefault()`. Try adding an ID to the button, remove `onclick` and in js: `$('#my-btn').on('click', function(e) { e.preventDefault() /* $.ajax(...) */ })`

Comment: I tried it, you can see my post's edit. But it's not working either

Comment: Are you sure the `url` is correct? I mean, isn't it 404 error? What do you see in the `Network` tab in the Chrome DevTools?

Comment: The PHP page does load when I click, but the POST values aren't set so it doesn't work. In the network tab everything seems ok.

Comment: I just tried with absolute directories like `http://localhost/test/sendData.php` and still nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> <form id="sendData" action="sendData.php" method="post">
>   <button type="submit" name="send" onclick="sendAjax()">Send</button>
> </form>
> ```

You're running the JS when you click a submit button in a form.

So the JS runs, then the browser immediately navigates to a new page (submitting the form, with no data in it, to the PHP) and the XMLHttpRequest object is destroyed before it receives a response.

You then see the result of the standard form submission.

If you just want a button to trigger some JavaScript, then use a non-submit button (`<button type="button"`), and don't put it in a form.

Better yet:

1. switch away from `onclick` attributes (they have a variety of issues) in favour of [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) providing a `submit` event listener on the form
2. Use [`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to stop the form submission when the JS is successful
3. Put form controls in the form so it submits useful data when the JS isn't successful

i.e. write [Unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) then provides [Progressive enhancement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement).

Comment: Okay, so the page at least doesn't refresh now. I've chenged my button to a normal one and my function to `$('#buttonID').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault();` but it does nothing now. Thanks for the links, by the way. I'm still using onlick for the button though

Comment: @ratuwipuy — Open the developer tools in your browser. Look at the Console. Click the button. See what errors come up. I expect something about `$` being undefined.

Comment: Okay so after adding `$(document).ready(function() {` before the click handler it works. Although the error message still pops up... Nothing in the console by the way. It's an error inside the ajax function

Comment: I've edited my post with exactly what I have, if you want to check it

Comment: You mean `alert("Error al pasar datos")` runs? Look at the arguments to the error function. There's some reason it is failing.

Comment: oooooh my god. I'm sorry for so much trouble. I've finally fixed it after removing this from my javascript file: https://www.pastiebin.com/5c6d3f7c166f1
I was getting errors reading a json file previously so I added it and then completely forgot. Really, thanks for your help, I hope you will have an amazing day :)

Answer (score -1):

Two things:

You need to tell jQuery to use the application/json content-type:

```
function sendAjax() {
  $.ajax({
    url:  "sendData.php",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      score: score,
      numQuiz: numQuiz
    },
    success: function() {
      alert("Data succesfully sent");
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("There has been an error");
    }
  })
}
```

PHP's $_POST variable is not populated as you think it is as the payload is not urlencoded as is standard with say a form submit. So we can parse the JSON payload (body) ussing:

```
$myData = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
var_dump($myData->score);
```

Comment: Your JS is *claiming* to be sending JSON, and your PHP is trying to parse JSON, but you're sending URL Form Encoded data, so that will fail.

Comment: What does json have to do with this? I get 
`Notice: Trying to get property '' of non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/sendData.php on line 10
NULL`

Comment: @quentin good catch! thank you.. we'd want to JSON.stringify(..) of course

Comment: Changing code that sends form encoded data, which claims to be form encoded data, to somewhere which expects form encoded data to code that sends JSON encoded data, which claims to be JSON encoded data, to somewhere which expects JSON encoded data … is pretty pointless and doesn't solve the problem.